# Second hard drive not visible after installing new disk and OS

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I installed Windows 10 to my new SSD while my old hard drive was disconnected. I did this because I wanted Windows to install everything (Bootloader, Rescue partition, etc) to the new SSD.

Afterwards I connected the old drive again and it didn't show up at all in Windows (not in diskpart, not in Disk Management, not in Windows Explorer). However, in BIOS I can see the drive with my old installation. I can also see it when I boot into the Windows Installer again (Install > ... > Select drive to install Windows - it shows up there with all partitions along with my SSD).

I need my old drive as there were additional partitions for my data which I now can not access anymore.

How do I access my old hard drive after booting the new OS on the new drive?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should use *[Disk Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management)* to check the state of the old drive now that the new OS is installed on the new SSD drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. It was a driver necessary to detect my second hard drive... Didn't know that we need a driver for HDDs showing up (even if the boot drive is working.

Just let Windows Update install some drivers and everything is working now.